# Fulltext search across sources: Gemara, Zohars, Rishonim and Aharonim

Tags: books-generally, internet, technology, sources-mekorot

I know about Hebrewbooks.org for searching for sources in books, but the problem is you have to get to let's say every Masechta to look for a phrase. Is there a program (doesn't have to be free) that lets you search for Gemara, Zohars, Rishonim, Aharonim, Roseh Yeshivot, Pesukim etc. and gives you all the sources for them?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Bar-Ilan Responsa project has an [online version](http://www.responsa.co.il/default.aspx?action=advancedSearch!yes) that allows free searches, displaying up to 150 words from each result. This is an extremely powerful program, as its textbase is "clean" and edited, as opposed to many other search programs (such as Hebrewbooks and Otzar HaChochma) which are mostly based on error-prone, OCR-derived text.

Comment: If you can find a nearby library which subscribes, you can get the full service.

Comment: @yitznewton I have a cousin who's name is Yitz and is from Newton...Pretty interesting! 

What I wanted to say was that would Goyishe libraries have it?

Comment: @Dave there is no way to thank you enough for this, I could use thing all day@

Comment: @H'Gabriel - I'll let you in on another secret: For $50 a year, you can get access to the Spertus online collection, which includes the full Bar-Ilan program, as well as DBS and Judaic Classics. See here (http://www.spertus.edu/content/feinberg-ecollection#overlay-context=content/online-resources).

Comment: Ashrecha WeTov Lach- Ashrecha BaOlam HaZe WeTov Lach BaOlam Haba (Berachot 8a). I just used the Bar Ilan search thing to find that source! LOL

Comment: @dave read my last comment please I forgot to tag you

Comment: @H'Gabriel a large enough library may have it, especially if they are either academic, or participate in a consortium. Bottom line, ask or check out the library's website.

Comment: Yep, use it all the time. [Touro College](http://www.touro.edu/) has a subscription, and if you're a student they let you use the full version from any browser (by logging in).

Comment: @HachamGabriel - "Ashrecha vetov lach" ashrecha baolam hazeh vetov lach leolam haba originally came from the pirkei avos ethics of our fathers.  The gemara (brachos) was after the mishna.

Comment: @Adam Interesting...

Answer (score 5):

At <http://www.hebrewbooks.org> there is a search feature where you can type in the phrase and it at times will lead you to the thing you are searching for. It is the box on the left of title.

Comment: I know but you have to search every Sefer to find each source. For example if I was looking for the words "Safek Deorayata LeHumra" I would have to go to every Masechta in Shas and search there. I want one where you search the phrase "Safek Deorayta LuHumra" and it brings let's say Shut HaRashba 2:233 and Hidushei HaRitva Gittin 76b or Ben Ish Hai Balak Halcha 7.

Comment: @H'Gabriel I don't understand, if you type "Safek Deorayata LeHumra" in hebrewbooks it *would* find it in all seforim that they have (without having to re-search it in a sefer)

Comment: I never realized that. I always ignored that sidebar. Well, I still like the Bar Ilan one better.

Answer (score 4):

[Sefaria.org](http://sefaria.org) matches the description you gave, and it is free of charge. As of 2018, their searchable database contains over 143 million words, ranging from Zohar to Shev Shamtsa with abundant cross referencing.

From their website:

> Sefaria is a non-profit organization dedicated to building the future of Jewish learning in an open and participatory way. We are assembling a free living library of Jewish texts and their interconnections, in Hebrew and in translation. With these digital texts, we can create new, interactive interfaces for Web, tablet and mobile, allowing more people to engage with the textual treasures of our tradition.

Comment: Note their search engine isn't very good. Hopefully they're improving it

Comment: @robev I’ve found it to be quite noteworthy, especially considering the price.