# Where can I find indexes to the classic Torah works?

Tags: torah-study, jewish-books

I want indexes (indices) to the classic Torah works, so that I can quickly find the pages that hold the information I need. Where can I find such indexes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Chumash:

  - The Stone Chumash, the Soncino chumash, and R' Aryeh Kaplan's chumash each include an index.
- Tanach:

  - The Stone Tanach includes an index.
- Talmud Bavli:

  - Retter, Daniel (2011) (in English).
    המפתח = HaMafteach.
    [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/774399427) — [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1583303308) — [promotional website](http://www.hamafteach.org/).
  - Retter, Daniel (2011) (in Hebrew).
    המפתח לתלמוד בבלי.‏
    [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/767499027) — [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006ODQ42) — [promotional website](http://www.hamafteach.org/he/home).
  - Some of the works listed under [Talmud -- Indexes](http://www.worldcat.org/search?q=su%3aTalmud+Indexes.) in WorldCat are other indexes to the Talmud. Most are not.
- Shulchan Aruch:

  - Karo, J. E., Isserles, M. I., Preisler, Z., Havlin, S. (1993) (in Hebrew).
    שלחן ערוך / לרבינו יוסף קארו ; עם המפה (הגהות הרמ״א) לרבינו משה איסרליס ; נערך, סודר והודפס מחדש בכרך אחד עם פיסוק ועם האיזכורים מהמקרא, מלווה בששה מפתחות ; בעריכת צבי ה. פרייזלר, שמואל הבלין.‏
    One-volume edition, fully vowelized, with indexes. No commentaries. [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/28810603/editions). Important: In WorldCat, use "Show libraries holding just this edition" to get a list of only the libraries that hold the 1993 Ketuvim edition and to get a list of only the libraries that hold the 1995 Ketuvim edition.
- Mishna Berurah:

  - Yad Yisrael by [Daniel Eidensohn](http://daattorah.blogspot.com/). English-language and Hebrew-language editions available.
- Igros Moshe:

  - Yad Moshe by [Daniel Eidensohn](http://daattorah.blogspot.com/).
- You can find indexes to other works too. For example, see <http://books.google.com/books?id=347YayHXEEcC&pg=PA115> and the succeeding pages.

Answer (score 3):

Check out two websites by Mordechai Torczyner:

- http://www.webshas.org/ -- Intelligent Index to the Talmud
- http://www.hamakor.org/ -- bibliographic help in researching topics within traditional Jewish literature

While not complete, they are worthwhile resources.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [The Bar Ilan Responsa - Global Jewish Database](http://responsa.biu.ac.il/). It is a database of thousands of years of halachic literature with an extremely advanced search feature, allowing you to find all relevant information in seconds.

Comment: Is this an index of the contents of the works, or just a lot of the works themselves?

Comment: It is a searchable database with extremely advanced search features that allows for quick searching of thousands of years of halachic literature.

Comment: Which is why it's a good answer to [this other question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12560/759) but I don't know if it works here.