# Is there a topic index for Igrot Moshe?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, moshe-feinstein

There are several topics that I offhand recall having seen in Igrot Moshe, but I have a tough time locating them.

Is there a topic index, or even better an online search that I can do to locate specific topics in Igrot Moshe?

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22629/759

Comment: related: [Which sections of Igros Moshe are in which volumes?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57624/11501)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a very popular sefer called *Yad Moshe* which is an index for Igros Moshe. [See here.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002Q3XN6C)

Answer (score 2):

Yad Moshe, the classic index to Igrot Moshe, authored by Daniel Eidensohn now [exists in English](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1456332147). It is printed on demand so shouldn't get out of stock.

Here is a sample picture

[image]