# Are there any tanakh search engines?

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach, technology, internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is there a good online source to check how often a word appears in Tanach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9425/where-is-there-a-good-online-source-to-check-how-often-a-word-appears-in-tanach/)

I'm looking to find instances where music, and musical instruments, is mentioned in Tanakh.

Oftentimes, more generally, I search for particular words in Tanakh, and it takes me a lot of time.

Is there a website where I can input words and receive results of instances of those words in Tanakh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TheTrugmans](http://thetrugmans.com/word-and-gematria-search/) and click on text.

Comment: I can't see my search results. I use the Bar Ilan search but that requires a subscription.

Answer (score 5):

[Mechon Mamre](http://mechon-mamre.org/) has a google custom search for tanach, both Masoretic, and with chaserot spelled out.

Answer (score 2):

Bar-Ilan and Otzar HaSefarim are good programs, but they are costly. A free program that I use with significantly fewer sefarim but a good search interface is Torat Emet (www.toratemetfreeware.com) -- it has the whole Tanakh and parshanim plus many other useful sefarim.
One note about torat emet -- you need to change the system locale of your computer to "Israel," so that the Unicode characters will show up. If you don't want to do that (there's no reason not to, it doesn't change anything else about your computer), there is also a program based off Torat Emet (though with fewer sefarim) called Orayta, which can be found on the above website. Orayta can also be used on OS X and Android devices [maybe also iOS, but I never tried].

Comment: Great resource that I never heard of. Thanks!

Comment: Orayta can be also used on Linux.

Comment: @jutky Did you try it? I couldn't make it work...

Comment: @Shokhet I used it once (about a year or two ago) and it was good. But now I see that their last build was on 2013-07-13 (https://launchpad.net/~moshe-wagner/+archive/orayta), maybe they just didn't created a distribution for newer versions. What version of Linux OS do you have?

Comment: @jutky Just playing around, trying to decide if it's worthwhile to dual-boot...the only one I tried it on was Mint 16 32 bit

Comment: I used it on Ubuntu. I'll try to install it once more and tell you if it works.