# Passuk-finder application

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach, internet

I am presently working on a siddur for personal use. However, one of my pet-peeves is when I am looking at a large block of text (let's say Hodu after Baruch She'amar in N"A) and I can't see any sources for the pesukim. Is there an application (Internet or Mac) which can be used to track down the origin of a group of pesukim in a passage?

Comment: You could plug each verse (or phrase) into a [search engine](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36218/5323), but if I understand your question you're looking for something more than that.

Comment: Yeah, I want to put in a whole block of text, like Hodu (as I said) or Va'ani K'ritecha (after Mah Tovu in my nusach) and get each passuk with it's origin.

Comment: Doesn't the Artscroll already have this in its siddur?

Comment: Yes, but some of the tefillot I say are not in Artscroll, thus making it useless for the purpose of this project.