# Parashiot Search Utility

Tags: product-recommendation

Shalom friends!

Is there such a service that keywords can be searched to find the **parasha where the keyword can be found.** For example if I typed the word "Moses" then all the parshiot in the Chumash containing that word would be listed along with clickable references? (Perhaps one searchable in English and in Hebrew). Sometimes I'm searching for something so I can check the Rashi in my Chumash, but what I mostly find in the search engine are many Christian references to the Bible, which is not at all what I'm looking for.

Toda raba!

Comment: For "Moses" you can just see here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5764/moshes-name-is-missing#comment91617_5764

Comment: Are you specifically looking for English language search?

Comment: Preferably English because my English is much more fluent than my Hebrew, although I can understand many words in the Torah once I've seen them, I don't think I would be able to search without starting in English. :)

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36218/759

Comment: Is there a specific translation you'd want to search?

Comment: https://mg.alhatorah.org/Concordance_Module_1Heb.html

Comment: Try this: https://www.chabad.org/search/results.aspx?scope=63255&searchword=MOSES#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=MOSES&gsc.page=1

Comment: @DoubleAA I suppose JPS, Artscroll, Koren Jerusalem

Comment: Those are all very helpful :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer was given in the comments by @Avrohom Yitzchok, who noted that Chabad specifies the result documents by parasha, rather than sefer.

See [this example](https://www.chabad.org/search/results.asp?searchWord=%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94&scope=63255#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94&gsc.sort=) looking for Moshe in Hebrew.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use the search engine on sefaria.org. It gives you a large amount of search options, so if you want to find Moses in the Chumash, you can select Tanakh and then the books of the Pentateuch, [like so](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=Moses&tab=text&tpathFilters=Tanakh%2FTorah&tvar=1&tsort=chronological&svar=1&ssort=relevance).

Once you find the verse you want, you can select your preferred translation.

Comment: alas, while Sefaria's search is pretty great, it doesn't descend to the parsha level, which was the question.

Comment: The OP said he wanted something to find the pasuk in the Chumash. Something that takes  you right to the pasuk is better than the parsha.

Comment: "to find the parasha where the keyword can be found", not the pasuk. the link in my answer (which was from @AvrohomYitzchok 's comment tells the parsha and from there you click and can search on the page. It can be useful for knowing, e.g., does the word gopher appear in parshas Noach? In which parshiyot does it occur? Huh, Moshe isn't mentioned in Tetzaveh. Following a direct link to a pasuk, where it also doesn't indicate the parsha it's found in, isn't helpful for such queries.

Comment: If you want to check the Rashi on a passuk, sefaria is your best bet. AlHatorah.org is pretty good too.

Answer (score 0):

The search function on [Bar Ilan](http://www.responsa.co.il/default.aspx?action=toggleLogin) is also free (it costs money to click onto the results, but you can see the titles which tell you the documents in which the search term appears).

Comment: The question, though, was parsha, and following the link, it doesn't seem that the documents include parsha.

Answer (score 0):

check out...
Soncino English Tanach & Talmud
https://jewishsoftware.com/soncino-english-tanach-talmud

one can limit search to Chumash or specific book(s), Tanach etc and will list results with exact number of times word or phrase shows  up -- it is clickable and will take one to the specific passage which also shows up in the results and is super fast.

also check out...
ArtScroll Tanach Jaffa Edition:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.artscroll.TANACH&hl=en
also has a very convienient search function that gives numbered results for how many times word shows up in Tanach or on current page, is clickable and will take one to the precise spot in Tanach

The Edmond J. Safra Digital Edition of the Chumash in English:
https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422628331.html
to limit search to Chumash

Bible Dictionary & Concordance for Android:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.jewishsoftware.bibledictionary&hl=en

Bible Dictionary & Concordance for PC:
https://jewishsoftware.com/download-bible-dictionary-concordance

Word by Word Bible Dictionary & Concordance for PC:
https://jewishsoftware.com/download-word-by-word-bible-dictionary-concordance

Comment: "one can limit search to Chumash or specific book(s)". The question, though, was parsha.

Comment: i hear...good to have this in handy as well for chapter and verse to parsha reference https://www.chabad.org/parshah/otherparshas_cdo/aid/9175/jewish/All-Parshahs.htm

Comment: That is a good reference to have in combination with searching the other sites. I'm going to print that page and put it in my study area! Toda!