# I am looking for the Torat Emet program to list verses for names

Tags: names, technology, internet

I am looking for a direct link to the Torat Emet program that helps you find verses for your hebrew name. I am looking for more verses for my name to use during the shmona esrei. I saw a [mention](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/50448/5323) of this program from Torat Emet under "shonot." I would like a set of verses that represent good health prosperity. grandchildren.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [link to Torat Emet Freeware](http://toratemetfreeware.com/index.html?downloads).

Comment: That works for windows people but nothing there for Linux fans

Comment: @Yossi this answer is still a good answer to this question, because this question asked for a specific piece of software. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31867/5323 for some other programs that do similar things

Comment: @Shokhet I did not say it was not a good answer, I only said it has nothing for Linux people. Also that link only has PDFs and online formats as well as software for Windows, Mac, etc etc. Nothing on there for Linux users to install

Comment: @Yossi fair. I understood it to be a criticism of the answer, because the program specified by the question post is Windows-specific, but it's true that one can't be expected to know that if they weren't already familiar with the program, like I was.